# There isn't any info about my test execution on the resulting tab of TestNG Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, testng

I'm using `Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)` and `TestNG` plug-in for it.

My `testng.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">
    <test name="test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="wp.LoginWaitLogout">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When I ran test using `TestNG` and this `xml` I can see, that browser is launched and test is running, I see messages in console, but on the resulting tab of `TestNG` I see endless process. Test passes or fails and I can see the result in report, but on on the resulting tab of `TestNG` I still see endless process.
Check screenshot:
[image]

I've tried:

1) reboot.

2) relaunch Eclipse.

3) reinstall `TestNG`.

4) search in the Internet didn't provide me any valuable info.

5) I've tried to launch this test in IntelliJ IDEA, but it looks strange:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the test method contained `System.exit(0);`. After removing `System.exit(0);` I can see the progress on the resulting tab of `TestNG`.